# Question on replace within the sample function

Tags: r

I just started using R.

I want to simulate a dice roll. Therefore, I set

```
z <- sample(6, 12, replace = TRUE)
```

What does the `replace` in this function mean? And why does it need to be `TRUE`?

And also is there any suggestion on looking up these little things contained in the function?

Thank you very much for your time and your help!

Comment: `replace = TRUE`  allows replacement when sampling, so you can draw a random variable and pick it next time again.

Comment: Any suggestion on looking up these little things contained in the function? Yes, run `help('sample')` at an R prompt.

Answer (score 0):

`?sample` will give you the documentation for the function. See the `Arguments` section.

From the docs, `replace` means "should sampling be with replacement?". When set to `TRUE` it means it can select the same element multiple times.

Answer (score -1):

you can write on your ***console**

```
?replace
```

and

```
?sample
```

It will give you more details